# What is the reason for the low video speed in the Face recognition with opencv-python?

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

#### This code works corectly , But it's a very slow .

I changed the **cv2.waitKey(1)** number. But it still didn't change much

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

facexml = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")                  
eyexml = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_eye.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("my_video.avi")                                         

while True:
    _,frame = cap.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                
    faces = facexml.detectMultiScale(gray)                            
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:                                       
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)          
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]                             
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]                          

        eyes = eyexml.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)                  
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:                                   
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,0,255),1)   

    cv2.imshow("window",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You're showing the video slowly, because you're showing a new frame after all your processing... which takes some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply a Harris cascade classifier is an old and slow algorithm for fast online face recognition in video. Try to read an OpenCV manual on [Cascade Classifier](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html) and reduce the number of scales by setting equal `maxSize` and `minSize` or set larger scaleFactor to decrease total amount of images computed from original image by resizing.